# Can't get column name when using HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-orm

I'm using Spring-orm and HibernateTemplate to execute a native SQL query (DB is Oracle 11 for the reference), like this:

```
@Override
public List<Object> executeNativeQuery(final String queryStr, final Map<String, String> params) {

    List<Object> results = this.template.execute(new HibernateCallback<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Object> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            // Get the query
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryStr);

            // Assign parameters to the query, if any
            if (params != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                    query.setString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }

            // fire the query
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Object> res = query.list();

            return res;
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```

I've managed to successfully execute the query and get the results back. But I couldn't figure out a way to also get the resulting column names, and I'm starting to think that's not possible using this approach.
My problem is that I have to execute a query that comes from user input and I have no clues about parameter names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way through it, so I post it hoping it'll be useful for others. I was doing it the wrong way, the correct way (at least for what my needs are) is to use `doWork`.

instad of:

```
session.createSQLQuery(queryStr);
```

I had to get the connection like this:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {

        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(queryStr);
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int col = md.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("Number of Column : " + col);
            System.out.println("Columns Name: ");
            for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
                String col_name = md.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println(col_name);
            }
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to get column names in Hibernate:

```
public ArrayList<String> getTableDesc(String tableName){

    System.out.println("getFieldNames:start"+tableName);
    Object[] a;
    List<Object[]> fieldNames = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    ArrayList<String> tabFieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
    String queryStr = "desc "+tableName;
    fieldNames = (List<Object[]>) session.createSQLQuery(queryStr).list();
    for(int i=0;i<fieldNames.size();i++){
        a = fieldNames.get(i);
        tabFieldNames.add(a[0].toString());
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception "+e);
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
    System.out.println("getFieldNames:end"+tabFieldNames.toString());
    return tabFieldNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResultTransformer` class to map the query result to an entity class.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17313

EDIT 1:

```
for( int i= 0; i< ((Object[])res.get(0)).length ; i++){
    //do something with data
    res.get(0)[i]
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, unfortunately. To use `ResultTransformer` you must provide a bean, which means that I know in advance how many colums will the query return, which I don't.

Comment: the fact is that `res` does not contain information about the columns, just the data returned by the query.

Comment: Thanks @fmucar, i finally found an answer and I posted it.